# How to change the permission of php functions in my windows laptop?

Tags: php, windows

The php functions copy(), rename() and some others are requesting permission when I trying to use them. So I wanted to know how can I change the permissions of php in my windows laptop. Thanks in advance.
It asked to grant permission..?

I tried to change the permission using chmod-- but I read that this applies only on unix powered computers.

Comment: Whatever account the PHP script is running under in IIS/Apache/YourWebserverOfChoice needs permissions to the relevant folders/files it's trying to work with. You can set those permissions via the normal windows file/folder permissions screens, or via the equivalent powershell commands.

Comment: on that note: remember to put the [missing details in your post](/help/how-to-ask): there are a million ways to use PHP on Windows, so which server solution are you using, which version of the server solution, and what configuration (both server and PHP itself) did you already assign it to make sure PHP can run properly. Because just PHP as a standalone scripting language should run "as you' when you run it, and shouldn't require UAC except for restricted folders (assuming you made sure to mark your own account as normal user account, with a separate admin account)

Comment: It is asking me to grant permission. Sorry guys I'm just a beginner in the programming world so ADyson can u clarify your answer to me..

Comment: It's asking you  to grant permission _when_? Explain (in detail) what are you doing that gets you to the UAC dialog. Do you have a webserver and you're accessing a page that PHP services? Do you _not_ have a webserver and you just have a small `.php` file that you're running on the commandline with `php myfile.php`? What locations are you trying to access relative to that script? etc.

Comment: I use Apache server php version 5.3 , its asking me to grant permission when I tried to rename a file in a directory...

Comment: So make sure to put that in your post, and then explain what PHP settings you told Apache to use. Also in your post. Details go in your post (you're not talking to folks in a comment thread, all requests for details are to make sure you update your post so that _everyone_ has the full picture by reading it). And then most importantly: did you search the web and SO for this problem already? PHP and Apache is the most common combination, and you're guaranteed not the first person to run into filewrite permissions on windows using that combination.

Comment: Side note: PHP 5.3 is years out of date and not supported anymore, please upgrade to a supported version urgently to continue to get new features and security fixes - see [PHP Supported Versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: `so ADyson can u clarify your answer to me`...well what specifically didn't you understand? The webserver runs as a different system user than the one you log into Windows with yourself, so it has different permissions. And I assume if you use Windows for any more than the most casual usage then you know that you can set permissions by right-clicking on a file or folder and going to its properties. Please [edit] your question with any and all clarifications to what you've been asked so far. We cannot guess what precisely you're doing or what your scenario is, unfortunately.